# Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'mPageScroll2id'

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, parallax

```
(function($){
       $(window).load(function(){
       /* Page Scroll to id fn call */
           ***$("#navigation-menu a,a[href='#top'],a[rel='m_PageScroll2id']").mPageScroll2id({
              highlightSelector:"#navigation-menu a"});***
            /* demo functions */
            $("a[rel='next']").click(function(e){
                  e.preventDefault();
                  var to=$(this).parent().parent("section").next().attr("id");
                  $.mPageScroll2id("scrollTo",to);
            });
        });
})(jQuery);
```

---

***$("#navigation-menu a,a[href='#top'],a[rel='m_PageScroll2id']").mPageScroll2id({
              highlightSelector:"#navigation-menu a"});***

Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'mPageScroll2id' is shown, can anyone help me to improve this piece of code.

Comment: did you include the plugin for `mPageScroll2id`

Comment: jquery.malihu.PageScroll2id.js is included

Comment: @ArunPJohny is that a way to do ***$...

Comment: Then either the plugin couldn't be loaded successfully or it doesn't have such a method. There is not much we can do. Use your browser's developer tools to figure out whether the plugin is loaded correctly and read the plugin's documentation.

Answer (score -1):

Remove

```
(function($){

})(jQuery);
```

And remove '* * *' in your code 
because self executing function can run before mPageScroll2id is loaded

Comment: sorry, but '* * *' its not there in code while highlighting it on stackoverflow  '* * *', is added.

I removed (function($){

})(jQuery); but error is still there

Comment: Why should removing `(function($){ })(jQuery);` fix the issue?